# Excel 97-2007 sheet issue not displaying data, completely blank 3

Tags: windows-7

[image]

IF both person doing same work we add attended by both name 
my query when both are attended same work person name i write subhash/pradeep 
it will add 1count  in subhash table and pradeep table

Comment: Please ignore subject line

Comment: Please find the image i having problem

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Please help me i try but i cant find solution

Comment: Have you checked out my edit.....

Comment: Then accepting the answer is good form...

Answer (score 0):

This finds the first two letters of each name and gives 1 if found, 0 if not. Cell C2 shows the formula entered in B2 and dragged down, idem for G2.

Edit, so after some meagre clarification and "I want..." Ha...
This also works:
[image]

Comment: i using this formula in table =COUNTIF($D$12:$D$497,"Subhash") My Query is when i write both person name in attended by any cell EXAMPLE subhash/pradeep automatic i will 1 count in subhash and pradeep

Comment: please find the image i allready add

Comment: i wants formula when i attended column i write subhash/pradeep name it will automatic add 1 count in table of subhash and pradeep

Comment: You should be able to use what I have provided and just sum the results... Or you could use the technique and apply it with countif() for example.

Comment: it will only add in count column1 column 2 is closed count i using this formula =COUNTIFS($F$12:$F$488,"closed",$D$12:$D$488,"Pradeep")

Comment: third column is open i use this formula=COUNTIFS($F$37:$F$43,"open",$D$37:$D$43,"pradeep")

Comment: its working now in all column

Comment: Check out why I used the asterisks each side of the names in my example...

Comment: sorry sir my formula was mismatch